# Ansible - fetch files from one remote node to another

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'd like to use Ansible to upload files from local workstations to a NAS server. Both are managed via Ansible.

The only way I've gotten this to work so far is by mounting the NAS file share as a local directory via NFS, and delegating the copy tasks to the Ansible controller:

```
  - name: Fetch files to NAS
    fetch:
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: "/NAS/Share/{{inventory_hostname}}/" #<local NFS mount
      flat: yes
      validate_checksum: yes
    with_items: "{{ found_files.files }}"
```

However, this solution is slow and error prone. In addition, I would like to start using Ansible tower, with which I don't think this solution will work at all.

Is this a feasible task to automate via Ansible?
The only solution I can think of is mounting the NAS to the workstations and copying it locally - something I'd prefer to avoid.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to the great commenters below! I managed to use the `synchronize` module from Linux workstations as suggested.

Unfortunately, some of the workstations run Windows, where the module isn't available.
The only currently working solution I could muster is using `pscp`, which I prefer to avoid to keep things Ansible-only.

Is there another method I can use to fetch files from Windows workstations to the NAS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are more options. For example, use *rsync* or *scp*

**rsync**

Use the module [*synchronize*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#ansible-posix-synchronize-module-a-wrapper-around-rsync-to-make-common-tasks-in-your-playbooks-quick-and-easy) if you can:

- Install *rsync* both on NAS and the workstations. See [*Notes*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#notes).
- Configure passwordless ssh from NAS to the workstations.

For example, create a project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── nas.yml
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

2 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

Declare and customize the variables

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/nas.yml 
---

# Customize below variables - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Resolvable host or IP
nas_host: "{{ hostvars[nas].ansible_host }}"

# Workstation user who can read the files
wrks_admin: admin

# NAS user who runs the upload script
nas_admin: admin

# Directory at controller keeps the public keys of nas_admin
nas_dir_pub_keys: /tmp/nas_pub_keys

# Directory at NAS to upload the files to
nas_dir_share: /tmp/ansible/share

# Script at NAS run by nas_admin to upload the files
nas_upload_script: /tmp/nas_upload_script.bash

# List of files to upload from the workstations to NAS
nas_upload:
  - /etc/passwd


# Do not change this - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# The variable wrks keeps the comma-separated list of
# worstations. Create a list of the workstations
nas_wrks: "{{ wrks.split(',') }}"

# Public key of nas_admin stored at controller
nas_key: "{{ nas_dir_pub_keys }}/{{ nas }}/home/{{ nas_admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

Create the inventory of the NAS server(s) and the workstations

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
[nas]
nas_4 ansible_host=10.1.0.74

[nas:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=true
ansible_python_interpreter=/bin/python3.6

[wrks]
wrks_1 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
wrks_2 ansible_host=10.1.0.17
wrks_3 ansible_host=10.1.0.63

[wrks:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=true
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

Create the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
---

# Mandatory variables:
#
#   nas ... NAS server
#   wrks .. Workstations; comma-separated list

- name: NAS ready
  hosts: "{{ nas }}"
  tasks:
    - fetch:
        src: "/home/{{ nas_admin }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
        dest: "{{ nas_dir_pub_keys }}"
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ nas_dir_share }}/{{ item }}"
        owner: "{{ nas_admin }}"
      loop: "{{ nas_wrks }}"
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ nas_upload_script }}"
        content: |
          {{ '#' }}!/usr/bin/bash
          {% for host in nas_wrks %}
          {% set wrks_host = hostvars[host].ansible_host %}
          {% for file in nas_upload %}
          scp {{ wrks_admin }}@{{ wrks_host }}:{{ file }} {{ nas_dir_share }}/{{ host }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        owner: "{{ nas_admin }}"
        mode: "u+x"

- name: Workstations ready
  hosts: "{{ wrks }}"
  tasks:
    - authorized_key:
        user: "{{ wrks_admin }}"
        key: "{{ lookup('file', nas_key) }}"

- name: Workstations upload files to NAS
  hosts: "{{ wrks }}"
  tasks:
    - synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ nas_dir_share }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        checksum: true
      delegate_to: "{{ nas }}"
      loop: "{{ nas_upload }}"
      register: out
      become_user: "{{ nas_admin }}"
    - debug:
        var: out
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
```

Run the playbook with the extra variables

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e nas=nas_4 -e wrks=wrks_2,wrks_3
```

In the first play *`NAS ready`*:

- Public key of *nas_admin* at *nas* is stored on the controller

```bash
shell> tree -a /tmp/nas_pub_keys/
/tmp/nas_pub_keys/
└── nas_4
    └── home
        └── admin
            └── .ssh
                └── id_rsa.pub

4 directories, 1 file
```

- Directories *nas_dir_share* for all workstations *wrks* are created on *nas*

```bash
nas_4> ssh admin@10.1.0.74 tree /tmp/ansible/share
tmp/ansible/share/
├── wrks_2
└── wrks_3
2 directories, 0 files
```

- Optionally, create a script to upload the files from the command line on NAS.

In the second play *`Workstations ready`*:

- Add the public key of *nas_admin* at *nas* to *authorized_keys* of *wrks_admin* on all workstations *wrks*

In the third play *`Workstations upload files to NAS`*:

- Pull the files in the list *nas_upload* from the workstations to *nas*
- Optionally, display registered results.

Run the playbook

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e nas=nas_4 -e wrks=wrks_2,wrks_3

PLAY [NAS ready] *****************************************************************************

TASK [fetch] *********************************************************************************
changed: [nas_4]

TASK [file] **********************************************************************************
changed: [nas_4] => (item=wrks_2)
changed: [nas_4] => (item=wrks_3)

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
ok: [nas_4]

PLAY [Workstations ready] ********************************************************************

TASK [authorized_key] ************************************************************************
ok: [wrks_3]
ok: [wrks_2]

PLAY [Workstations upload files to NAS] ******************************************************

TASK [synchronize] ***************************************************************************
changed: [wrks_2 -> nas_4(10.1.0.74)] => (item=/etc/passwd)
changed: [wrks_3 -> nas_4(10.1.0.74)] => (item=/etc/passwd)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [wrks_2]
skipping: [wrks_3]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
nas_4: ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
wrks_2: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
wrks_3: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

The files in the list *nas_upload* were copied from the workstations *wrks* to *nas_dir_share* on *nas*

```bash
nas_4> tree /tmp/ansible/share/
/tmp/ansible/share/
├── wrks_2
│   └── passwd
└── wrks_3
    └── passwd

2 directories, 2 files
```

---

**scp**

Use the script *nas_upload_script* if you:

- Can't install rsync on NAS and the workstations. But, you
- Can configure passwordless ssh from NAS to the workstations.

```bash
admin@nas_4> cat /tmp/nas_upload_script.bash 
#!/usr/bin/bash
scp admin@10.1.0.17:/etc/passwd /tmp/ansible/share/wrks_2
scp admin@10.1.0.63:/etc/passwd /tmp/ansible/share/wrks_3
```

Skip the third play and run the script on *nas* from the command line

```bash
admin@nas_4> /tmp/nas_upload_script.bash 
passwd                                  100% 2958   595.8KB/s   00:00    
passwd                                  100% 1708   375.5KB/s   00:00
```

---

Notes:

- If you can install Ansible on NAS the trivial option would be to run a play there
- It's also possible to create a script to *rsync* the files from the command line on NAS
- The values of *nas_admin* and *wrks_admin* may be different from *ansible_user*
- The task *copy* in the first play is optional. You can remove it if you don't need the script.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use the Ansible syncronize module which does rsync under the covers.  That would possibly speed up the copy if there are files which don't get updated so they would not be transfered.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html